# Excel: I need a formula that will count months between two dates. If it's 1-15 it should be a half month. Any ideas?

Tags: microsoft-excel

So I am trying to find a formula for excel. Bascically I have two dates and I need to know the number of months between them. But to add complexity, I need a rule in there that if the earlier date is the 1st to 15th it will be a whole month but if it is 16th to end of the month it will be a half month.

For example:
Date 1: April 4, 2012
Date 2: December 31, 2012
Answer: Number of months would be 9 months

If Date 1 was April 16, 2012, with the same Date 2 of December 31, 2012, then the number of months would equal 8.5.

Can anyone help me with this one? You help would be greatly appreciated.
many thanks

Comment: Not a programming question. should have been asked at Super User

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the dates are in G8, H8

```
=DATEDIF(G8, H8, "m") +1 -IF(DAY(G8) <16,0, 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: Wow that took a few goes to get right :-)

Comment: Didn't work for me. I got the error #VALUE!

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010.

Comment: So am I. Both my dates are in date format, same format but doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: my contact details are in my profile. send me a sample excel sheet and I'll have a quick look

Comment: Date 1     Date 2 Answer
10/01/12 12/31/12  #VALUE! 
10/19/12 12/31/12  #VALUE!

Comment: Great - I got it working. thanks for your help. is there anyway I can max the number to 12?

Comment: Try wrapping Preet's formula with MIN - e.g. =MIN(12,orig_formula)

Answer (score 1):

If someone want's a more precise solution for month fractions, they could use

```
=(date1 - date2)/(365/12)
```

It considers a month to be on average 365/12 days long,

I can use it for simple (approximate) monthly interest calculations like this one:

*$1000 charged 1.5% per month from the day of this posting until the current date*

```
=1000*(1.015)^( (TODAY()-DATE(2018,2,6))/(365/12) )
```